# React Native Background Geolocation - iOS

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, location

I am trying to build an app that tracks a user's location while they are driving their car. I am able to get the user's location while it is the main app running (in the foreground) by using react-native-geolocation, but am trying to figure out how to use it in the background so that they don't need to be using the app to track them (sort of like a running app or even other Map apps.

I am using the library @mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation. I set up the permissions properly (I believe), but am experiencing a weird error. For the sake of being short, I won't paste the entire file that I am using, but I am essentially using the code used in this example: https://gist.github.com/jonasgroendahl/c4fad8fa48f955b993d928e1c36d76f7

The issue comes when I call BackgroundGeolocation.start() inside the BackgroundGeolocaiton.checkStatus() call. The event listeners 'foreground', 'background', and 'stop' all work. The check status produces the following values: status.isRunning -> false, status.locationServicesEnabled -> true, status.authorization -> 99.

When I call start(), the app immediately exits and crashes. No errors are thrown, so it is tough to pinpoint what the issue is. When I reopen the app, it crashes as soon as I reach the page that the start() method is called in. The 'foreground' and 'background' events trigger properly (when it is in each respective state).

Things I have tried:

1. Setup Info.plist properties
2. Enabled Background Modes: Location Updates in Xcode.

Potential issues that I am trying to maneuver:

1. Using React Native Geolocation library in another part of the app to grab location once. If I can figure this library out, I can replace other library (react-native-geolocation) with react-native-background-geolocation to do everything.

Comment: Did you look up logs in Xcode? App crash may be a native error.

Comment: Turns out that you can't do background tasks with an iOS simulator. Calling start() crashed the iOS simulator because it uses a background task API in order to tell the phone to continue running it if it goes into the background. Calling this background task caused the app to crash, from my understanding of this.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that you can't do background tasks with an iOS simulator. Calling start() crashed the iOS simulator because it uses a background task API in order to tell the phone to continue running it if it goes into the background. Calling this background task caused the app to crash, from my understanding of this.